# How to pass action down as a prop in React Native and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

in parent Browse.js

```
import { usersFetch, onToggleFollow } from '../actions';

class Browse extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
       ....
        renderRow={(user) =>
          <UserItem user={user}
            onPress={() => this.props.onToggleFollow()}
          />}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { usersFetch, onToggleFollow })(Browse);
```

in the child UserItem.js

```
class UserItem extends Component {

  render() {
    followButton = <Button title='Follow' onPress={() => {
      this.props.onToggleFollow();
    }}/>;

    return (
      <View style={styles.cardContainerStyle}>
        <View>
          { followButton }
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

in the action creator file:

```
export const onToggleFollow = () => {
  console.log('onToggleFollow method!');

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: ON_TOGGLE_SUCCESS });
  };
};
```

I get an error says: "this.props.onToggleFollow is not a function, this.props.onToggleFollow is undefined" in UserItem.js, any helps thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is on this line:

```
onPress={() => { this.props.onToggleFollow(); }}
```

in `UserItem`. You passed in the function as `onPress` prop so you should be calling `this.props.onPress` instead.